# How to use the esc key to close lightbox page overlay

Tags: lightbox, arrow-keys

I have a question about a lightbox see [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sambodhiprem/R9RGJ/4/).
Clicking on one of the images opens a bigger version of the painting as a page overlay.

How to use the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to close this page overlay?

And how to use the arrow keys to move to the next image?

What kind of jQuery plugin / javascript would I need to make this happen?

```
<ul class="lb-album">

                    <li>
                        <a href="#Fly-My-Pretties-Walled-Garden">
                            <img src="http://sandipa.com.au/images/works-for-sale/thumbs/Fly-my-Pretties-Walled-Garden-sm.jpg" alt="Fly My Pretties: Walled Garden">
                            <span>Fly My Pretties</span>                        </a>
          <div class="lb-overlay" id="Fly-My-Pretties-Walled-Garden">
                            <a href="#page" class="lb-close">x Close</a>
                            <img src="http://sandipa.com.au/images/2010-2011/1000px-wide/Fly-my-Pretties-Walled-Garden.jpg" alt="Fly My Pretties: Walled Garden">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Fly My Pretties: Walled Garden<span>mixed media on canvas</span></h3>
                                <p>72 x 137 cm</p>
                                <a href="#Light-that-Shapes-the-Shadows" class="lb-prev">Prev</a>
                                <a href="#Central-Highlands-Circle-of-Gold" class="lb-next">Next</a>                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

<li>
                        <a href="#Central-Highlands-Circle-of-Gold">
                            <img src="http://sandipa.com.au/images/works-for-sale/thumbs/Central-Highlands-Circle-of-Gold-sm.jpg" alt="Central Highlands: Circle of Gold">
                            <span>Circle of Gold</span>                     </a>
          <div class="lb-overlay" id="Central-Highlands-Circle-of-Gold">
                            <a href="#page" class="lb-close">x Close</a>
                            <img src="http://sandipa.com.au/images/works-for-sale/Central-Highlands-Circle-of-Gold.jpg" alt="Central Highlands: Circle of Gold">
                            <div>
                                <h3>Central Highlands: Circle of Gold<span>mixed media on canvas</span></h3>
                                <p>51 x 108 cm</p>
                                <a href="#Fly-My-Pretties-Walled-Garden" class="lb-prev">Prev</a>
                                <a href="#Guardian-of-the-Night" class="lb-next">Next</a>                           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

A full implementation of Pure Javascript Lightbox or Image Popup Modal is available in one my Answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67169851/8210884.

This Answer mentioned in the link above allows handling both the issues of Hiding Lightbox with **ESC** key as well as navigating through images in Lightbox using **Left** and **Right** arrow key.

Here are the Pieces of code from that Answer which will help us achieve these Two issues.

Hiding the Lightbox with **ESC** key :

```
  if(event.keyCode==27){ // If ESC key is pressed
    if(document.getElementById("lightbox-container").classList.contains("showcontainer")){ // LIGHTBOX ON
      document.getElementById("lightbox-container").classList.remove("showcontainer");
    }
  }
```

Navigating through all the images on a Webpage in Lightbox with **Left and Right Arrow key** :

```
else if(event.keyCode==37) { // Left arrow key
    if(document.getElementById("lightbox-container").classList.contains("showcontainer")){ // LIGHTBOX ON
      // first get the URL of image displayed in the LIGHT BOX
      var currimgsrc = document.getElementById("lightbox-cont-img").getAttribute("src");

      // now match the sequence number in the array 
      var serialofarray = 0;
      for(k=0;k<allimgurlarray.length;k++){
        if(currimgsrc == allimgurlarray[k][2]){
          serialofarray = allimgurlarray[k][0];
        }
      }

      // with LEFT arrow, we are supposed to reduce the sequence and then use its ATTR SRC to LIGHT BOX
      if(serialofarray<=0){
        serialofarray = allimgurlarray.length - 1;
      }
      else {
        serialofarray = serialofarray - 1;
      }
      console.log("Left Arrow : "+serialofarray);
      document.getElementById("lightbox-cont-img").setAttribute("src", allimgurlarray[serialofarray][2]);

    }
  }
  else if(event.keyCode==39) { // Right Arrow Key
    if(document.getElementById("lightbox-container").classList.contains("showcontainer")){
      // first get the URL of image displayed in the LIGHT BOX
      var currimgsrc = document.getElementById("lightbox-cont-img").getAttribute("src");

      // now match the sequence number in the array 
      var serialofarray = 0;
      for(l=0;l<allimgurlarray.length;l++){
        if(currimgsrc == allimgurlarray[l][2]){
          serialofarray = allimgurlarray[l][0];
        }
      }

      // with RIGHT arrow, we are supposed to increase the sequence and then use its ATTR SRC to LIGHT BOX
      if(serialofarray>=allimgurlarray.length-1){
        serialofarray = 0;
      }
      else {
        serialofarray = serialofarray + 1;
      }
      console.log("Right Arrow : "+serialofarray);
      document.getElementById("lightbox-cont-img").setAttribute("src", allimgurlarray[serialofarray][2]);
    }
  }
```

These conditional cases related to **Key Pressing events** are tackled in `document.onkeydown = function(event)`.

---

This piece of code below is very important for disabling the **default behaviours** of Key pressing events on IMG tags as well as **stacking up all the images on a webpage** in an Array to allow Navigation in Lightbox with Left and Right arrow key.

```
// Select all A tags with IMG child nodes
var atagswithimgtag = document.querySelectorAll("a[href]");

// then prevent the default behaviour of A tags by preventing of opening new page by HREF
// as well as collect all the HREF of A tags with images to enable RIGHT and LEFT arrow key
var allimgurlarray = [];
for(i=0;i<atagswithimgtag.length;i++){
  var childAIMGtag = atagswithimgtag[i].childNodes;
  if (childAIMGtag[0].nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE) // or if (el[i].nodeType != 3)
  {
    // this seems too be a A tag with IMG tag as Childnode

    // first we need to prevent the default behaviour of opening the IMG in New Tab
    atagswithimgtag[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    // second is when we need to fill image URL aray with A HREF
    var listofnodes = atagswithimgtag[i];
    allimgurlarray[i] = [];
    allimgurlarray[i][0] = i;
    allimgurlarray[i][1] = " Image URL is ";//listofnodes.getAttributeNode("title").value;
    allimgurlarray[i][2] = listofnodes.getAttributeNode("href").value;
  }
  console.log(childAIMGtag[0].innerHTML);
}
```